# How to add 'data-href' to new table row in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

My table rows look like that:

```
<tr data-href="3571">
  <td>12 Jan 2020</td>
  <td>3563$</td>
</tr>
```

I would like to append new rows to the table with different *data-href* values, I have the following:

```
var billsTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
var newRow = billsTable.insertRow();
var newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
newCell1.innerHTML= bill.date;
var newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
newCell2.innerHTML= bill.total;
```

But I don't know how to add the *data-href* to the new row (*newRow* var in the above code)

Answer (score 0):

If this new row is a DOM object then you can directly set an attribute

```
 newRow.setAttribute("data-href", 1234);
```

Reference: [Mozilla Developer Network: setAttriute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)